# Expression to create instance and set members not using MemberInit

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

I need to create an instance and set some properties. Normally I would use `Expression.MemberInit(Expression.New(type), memberBindings)`, but I need to create the instance by calling a custom method instead. I can't figure out how to set members on the instance expression.

I'm creating the instance like this. I'm not actually using `Activator.CreateInstance`, but it should work for this example.

```
var method = typeof( Activator ).GetMethod( nameof( Activator.CreateInstance ), new Type[] { typeof( Type ) } );
Expression expression = Expression.Call( method, Expression.Constant( typeof( TestClass ) ) );
```

After I have the expression to create the instance, how can I set the objects members?

Comment: Normally, without using expression trees, you can't set the properties of an object created with a method call with a single expression, can you? You need at least two trees.

Comment: You can using `Expression.Block` or a multicast delegate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible to create such expression with [`Expression.Block`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.block(v=vs.110).aspx), but note that it can be used only to compile lambda delegate since the expression blocks are not supported by C# compiler and query providers other than LINQ to Objects.

Let first make sure the create instance method returns the correct type:

```
var method = typeof(Activator).GetMethod(nameof(Activator.CreateInstance), new Type[] { typeof(Type) });
var newObj = Expression.Convert(Expression.Call(method, Expression.Constant(typeof(TestClass))), typeof(TestClass));
```

and assuming you already have a list of `MemberAssignment` expressions which you'd normally use with `Expression.MemberInit`:

```
IEnumerable<MemberAssignment> memberBindings = ...;
```

Then the expression in question can be build as follows:

```
var obj = Expression.Variable(newObj.Type, "obj");
var expressions = new List<Expression>();
expressions.Add(Expression.Assign(obj, newObj));
expressions.AddRange(memberBindings.Select(b => Expression.Assign(
    Expression.MakeMemberAccess(obj, b.Member), b.Expression)));
expressions.Add(obj);
var variables = new Expression[] { obj };
var result = Expression.Block(variables, expressions);
```

So we create a variable called `obj`, assign the result of the object creating method, then generate member assignments for each member binding, and finally return the `obj` (the last expression in the block expression list).

Comment: There were a couple things blocking me here. My `List<MemberAssignment>` was `List<MemberBinding>` and didn't need to be. `MemberBinding` doesn't have the `Expression` property on it. The other thing was assigning the results of the method call to a variable. That makes total sense but I have never done it before. Thanks!